# run interpreter after execute bash python

Tags: python, bash, interpreter

Obviously it helps to have the interpreter to debug, but I prefer to execute commands in terminal. Is there any way to make it run the python program, then startup an interpreter with the variables and functions created already in there. My current command is this:

```
python main.py < tests/1.in
```

Does anyone know how to modify it to make the variables and functions accessible after runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-i` flag:

```
python -i main.py < tests/1.in
```

Comment: That Flag appears to work with simply `python -i main.py`.
However, when I try giving it stdin from a file, it doesn't allow for interactivity. Is there anything I can do to change that?

Answer (score 2):

Houw about [`-i`](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-i):

```
-i     : inspect interactively after running script; forces a prompt even
         if stdin does not appear to be a terminal; also PYTHONINSPECT=x
```